# Crash when calling UITableView's reloadData too soon after each other

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a text field that show a table view of suggestions as the user types a name. The filtering of the data source is made in a background thread because it can take some time.

```
- (IBAction)personNameChanged:(UITextField *)sender
{
    NSString *name = sender.text;

    [backgroundThread performBlock:^{
            [self.personsDataSource filterDataSourceByName:name];
            [mainThread performBlock:^{
                [self.autoCompleteTableView reloadData];
            }];
    }];
}
```

`[UITableView reloadData]` calls:

- `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

...synchronously while all cells:

- `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

...are called at a later point in time.

The problem is when the user is typing fast it can happen that `filterDataSourceByName` is called before all cells have loaded. Then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called for an indexPath that doesn't exist.

**How should you solve this problem when calling reloadData too fast so that is hasn't loaded all cells from the last reload?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The assigment of the new data source array for the table view must also be done on the main thread, something like:

```
- (IBAction)personNameChanged:(UITextField *)sender
{
    NSString *name = sender.text;
    [backgroundThread performBlock:^{
            // Store filtered array into separate array here:
            NSArray *filteredPersons = [self.personsDataSource filterDataSourceByName:name];
            [mainThread performBlock:^{
                // Assign to table view data source array here:
                self.dataSourceArray = filteredPersons;
                [self.autoCompleteTableView reloadData];
            }];
    }];
}
```

Otherwise it can happen that the data source array is modified on the background thread while being accessed by the table view on the main thread.

Comment: Seems to work, thanks! Just a question; this solution is dependent on that all cells are loaded before we can enter the mainThread block above again. Are we sure that all loading of the cells happens before we enter mainThread performBlock a second time?

Comment: @thejaz: I don't see why this depends on which cells are loaded or not.

Comment: The problem with my solution was that the array was filtered before all cells had been loaded, and when one cell tried to load after the array had changed - thats when I got my error. In your scenario - the only possible reason to get the same error again is if the table view starts to load all its cells. But before it is done with all cells, the mainThread performBlock is executed again. So the question is if mainThread performBlock can be executed before the loading of the cells. I guess that depends how the loading of the cells are placed in some sort of a queue?

Comment: @thejaz: I don't think there is any problem. (And note that the table view never loads *all* cells, only the visible cells.) The cells are loaded on the main thread. If you call `reloadData` (also on the main thread) then all visible cells are reloaded.

Comment: I know the cells are loaded on the main thread. But it doesn't load synchronously when calling reloadData, so it happens some time after that. That's why I'm worried that the code above will be executed again before all cells have been loaded. Maybe the cell loading is placed in the same queue as mainThread performBlock, then it always loads the cells before I can update the dataSourceArray. But I don't know how the cells are loaded, I only know it doesn't happen directly when I call reloadData (which I thought it did).